# Associate two mongoose databases in express app

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have two mongoose DB schema, a `User` and a `Profile`:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    type:     String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

---

```
var profileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: { 
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    email: { 
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },
    skill: { 
        type: String,
        default: ""
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Profile", profileSchema);
```

I am first registering and authenticating a user using [passport-js](http://www.passportjs.org), and if this is successful, I then want to create populate the `Profile` db with `username` and `type`. I will then allow users to update this `Profile` db (but not the `Users`). Following the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) I am trying to use `.populate`, to create an entry in `Profile` with the same information as in `User`:

```
router.post("/signup", function(req, res) {
    var newUser = new User({username: req.body.username, type: req.body.type});

    User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            console.log(err.message);
            return res.render("signup");
        }
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
            Profile.findById(newUser._id).populate("username").exec(function(err, foundUser){
                if(err){
                    console.log("Problem populating the profiles DB");
                }
                else{
                    console.log("New user:" + newUser._id);
                    res.redirect("profile/" + newUser._id);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

This passes without error, but my `Profiles` db is empty.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

I have also tried (within the same route):

```
Profile.create(newUser, function(err, newlyCreated){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Added user to profile db:" + newUser._id);
        console.log("New user:" + newUser._id);
        res.redirect("profile/" + newUser._id);
     }
 });
```

But this fails with error:

```
{ DocumentNotFoundError: No document found for query "{ _id: 5c6d9512a4a301b73b565681 }"
```

Another approach I'm trying is this:

```
Profile.create({username:req.body.username, type: req.body.type}, function(err, pro){
  if(err){
      console.log("Profile error: " + err);
  } else {
      console.log("Added user to profile db:" + newUser._id);
      console.log("New user:" + newUser._id);
      res.redirect("profile/" + newUser._id);
  }
});
```

Which passes, but produces an entry in `Profiles` with an `_id` different from the corresponding entry in `Users`.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Several parts of your code are problematic.

You called `newUser._id` however newUser is an instantiation of the mongoose model User. The `_id` field is created by MongoDB when storing a document to the db, so it's logical the field isn't filled when just instantiating an object. It is created when saving it to the db. So you can access the correct `_id` on `user._id`, with `user` coming from the callback.

```
router.post("/signup", function(req, res) {
    var newUser = new User({username: req.body.username, type: req.body.type});

    User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            console.log(err.message);
            return res.render("signup");
        }
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
            Profile.findById(user._id).populate("username").exec(function(err, foundUser){
                if(err){
                    console.log("Problem populating the profiles DB");
                }
                else{
                    console.log("New user:" + user._id);
                    res.redirect("profile/" + user._id);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Moreover you have strange parts in your code:

- You don't create a new profile in your `profiles` collection when creating a user. So how do you think it can find an document which wasn't created.
- You're calling `.findById` on Profile and passing it an `_id` from a User document, whereas it's not an `_id` of this db, so there is no document with the queried `_id` in this collection.
- You should query for `Profile.findOne({username: user.name})` and then try to populate on your field: `Profile.findOne({username: user.name}).populate('user')`
  with `profile.user = user._id` when storing the profile.
- Moreover, if you can have User username conflicts, then you should use the `user._id` to find the related documents, so store a unique value to your profile to find it easily.

So your schema should look a bit different:

```
var profileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: { 
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    email: { 
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },
    skill: { 
        type: String,
        default: ""
    }
});
```

and when populated through this call `Profile.findOne({user: user._id}).populate('user')` as a result you'll get:

```
{
    user: {
        username,
        password,
        type
    },
    email,
    skill
}
```

Remember:

- You cannot assign a string to mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
- Do not forget to create a Profile when creating a user, and reference the `user._id` inside your `profile.user` attribute.
- `Collection.findById(id)` will look for a document **inside the collection** with `document._id === id`
- If you want to populate on a field which is not typed as an objectId you have to define a **virtual**. Mongoose doc explains well this: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals
- If you don't want to send the password when populating, you can restrict the fields: `Profile.findOne({user user._id}).populate({path: 'user', select: "-password"})` . This request will remove the password field to reduce data leakage risks.

Comment: Thank you very much fo this generous answer. I will attempt to implement your suggestions tomorrow.